# Nested Select not working in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
FROM (
 SELECT upper(name), salary, deductions["service tax"] as service_tax,
 round(salary * (1 - deductions["service tax"])) as salary_minus_service_taxes
 FROM employees
 ) e
 SELECT e.name, e.salary_minus_service_taxes
 WHERE e.salary_minus_service_taxes > 70000;
```

When I run the above query I get below error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 6:10 Invalid column
>   reference 'name'

Comment: improve forming for code

Answer (score 0):

The column should be aliased:

```
SELECT upper(name) as name
```